# Please check my answers on these Convergence Problems

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of random variables with corresponding distribution functions given by $F_n(x)=0$ if $x<-n$, $F_n(x)=\dfrac{x+n}{2n}$ if $-n\leq x< n$ and $F_n(x)=1$ if $x\geq n$. Does $F_n$ converge to a distribution function?

My answer:

> No, because the limit function is $F(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ for all $x$, which is not a distribution function.

Second problem:

> Suppose $X_1,X_2,...$ be i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ random variables. Consider the sequence of random variables $\bar{X}_n$ where $\bar{X}_n=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}$. Let $F_n$ be the distribution function of $\bar{X_n}$, $n=1,2,...$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(x)$. Is this limit a distribution function?

My solution:

> No, because the limit function is $F(x)=0$ if $x<0$, $F(0)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $F(x)=1$ if $x>0$. So $F$ is not right continuous and fails to be a distribution function.

Actually I am learning these Convergence Concepts now and would like to make sure my methods are fine before making further progress.